# good jni framework for usage?

Tags: java-native-interface

We are planning to use jni in our project to invoke .dll for development and .so for prod.

Could you please let me know which jni frameworks are good in this with respect to ease of development and performance.

Thanks and Regards
Srinivasan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest this [one](http://code.google.com/p/android-cpp-sdk/).
It's a bit difficult to understand how to use it, but it's good.

Answer (score 0):

JNA is good in this. Also, you should use JNAerator to generate the poxy Javatypes.